# Load pretrained model and use it to train on small dataset

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network, torchvision, pre-trained-model

I am new to transfer learning and I need some guideline please:

I would like to use a pretrained model in this link :

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_yaxaXEINqAD-jlSqxtz1yIsor_0Lwam/view)

How I can load the pretrained model and fine tuning it by freeze the first layers  and then train it again on different data(small data of 1000 image)

update :
I loaded my models and I got this error of size mismatch :

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Generator:   size
> mismatch for crop_encoder.bn1.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 128]).     size mismatch for
> crop_encoder.bn2.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 256]).     size mismatch for
> crop_encoder.bn3.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 512]).     size mismatch for
> crop_encoder.bn4.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 1024]).    size mismatch for
> crop_encoder.bn5.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 2048]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 2048]).    size mismatch for
> layout_encoder.embedding.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 64]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 64]).  size mismatch for
> layout_encoder.bn1.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 128]).     size mismatch for
> layout_encoder.bn2.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 256]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 256]).     size mismatch for
> layout_encoder.bn3.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 512]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 512]).     size mismatch for
> layout_encoder.bn4.embed.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([6, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([7, 1024]).

and this is my code :

```
   import torch
    import argparse
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
    from models.generator_128 import Generator
    from models.discriminator import ImageDiscriminator
    from models.discriminator import ObjectDiscriminator
    from models.discriminator import add_sn
    from data.coco_custom_mask import get_dataloader as get_dataloader_coco
    from data.vg_custom_mask import get_dataloader as get_dataloader_vg
    from data.publaynet_custom_mask import get_dataloader as get_dataloader_publaynet
    from utils.model_saver import load_model, save_model, prepare_dir
    from utils.data import imagenet_deprocess_batch
    from utils.miscs import str2bool
    import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
    
    
    def main(config):
        cudnn.benchmark = True
        device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
        log_save_dir, model_save_dir, sample_save_dir, result_save_dir = prepare_dir(config.exp_name)
    
        if config.dataset == 'publaynet':
            data_loader, _ = get_dataloader_publaynet(batch_size=config.batch_size, COCO_DIR=config.coco_dir)
        vocab_num = data_loader.dataset.num_objects
    
        assert config.clstm_layers > 0
    
        netG = Generator(num_embeddings=vocab_num,
                         embedding_dim=config.embedding_dim,
                         z_dim=config.z_dim,
                         clstm_layers=config.clstm_layers).to(device)
        netD_image = ImageDiscriminator(conv_dim=config.embedding_dim).to(device)
        netD_object = ObjectDiscriminator(n_class=vocab_num).to(device)
    
        netD_image = add_sn(netD_image)
        netD_object = add_sn(netD_object)
    
        netG_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), config.learning_rate, [0.5, 0.999])
        netD_image_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(netD_image.parameters(), config.learning_rate, [0.5, 0.999])
        netD_object_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(netD_object.parameters(), config.learning_rate, [0.5, 0.999])
    
        print('load model from: {}')
        netG.load_state_dict(torch.load("/home/user/PycharmProjects/synth_doc_layout/layout2im/checkpoints/pretrained/iter-300000_netG.pkl"))
        netD_image.load_state_dict(torch.load("/home/user/PycharmProjects/synth_doc_layout/layout2im/checkpoints/pretrained/iter-300000_netD_image.pkl"))
        netD_object.load_state_dict(torch.load("/home/user/PycharmProjects/synth_doc_layout/layout2im/checkpoints/pretrained/iter-300000_netD_object.pkl"))
    
        data_iter = iter(data_loader)
    
        #if start_iter < config.niter:
    
        if config.use_tensorboard: writer = SummaryWriter(log_save_dir)
    
        for i in range(data_iter, config.niter):
            try:
                batch = next(data_iter)
            except:
                data_iter = iter(data_loader)
                batch = next(data_iter)
    
                # =================================================================================== #
                #                             1. Preprocess input data                                #
                # =================================================================================== #
            imgs, objs, boxes, masks, obj_to_img = batch
            z = torch.randn(objs.size(0), config.z_dim)
            imgs, objs, boxes, masks, obj_to_img, z = imgs.to(device), objs.to(device), boxes.to(device), \
                                                    masks.to(device), obj_to_img, z.to(device)
    
                # =================================================================================== #
                #                             2. Train the discriminator                              #
                # =================================================================================== #
    
                # Generate fake image
            output = netG(imgs, objs, boxes, masks, obj_to_img, z)
            crops_input, crops_input_rec, crops_rand, img_rec, img_rand, mu, logvar, z_rand_rec = output
    
                # Compute image adv loss with fake images.
            out_logits = netD_image(img_rec.detach())
            d_image_adv_loss_fake_rec = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 0))
    
            out_logits = netD_image(img_rand.detach())
            d_image_adv_loss_fake_rand = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 0))
    
            d_image_adv_loss_fake = 0.5 * d_image_adv_loss_fake_rec + 0.5 * d_image_adv_loss_fake_rand
    
                # Compute image src loss with real images rec.
            out_logits = netD_image(imgs)
            d_image_adv_loss_real = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 1))
    
                # Compute object sn adv loss with fake rec crops
            out_logits, _ = netD_object(crops_input_rec.detach(), objs)
            g_object_adv_loss_rec = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 0))
    
                # Compute object sn adv loss with fake rand crops
            out_logits, _ = netD_object(crops_rand.detach(), objs)
            d_object_adv_loss_fake_rand = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 0))
    
            d_object_adv_loss_fake = 0.5 * g_object_adv_loss_rec + 0.5 * d_object_adv_loss_fake_rand
    
                # Compute object sn adv loss with real crops.
            out_logits_src, out_logits_cls = netD_object(crops_input.detach(), objs)
            d_object_adv_loss_real = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits_src,
                                                                            torch.full_like(out_logits_src, 1))
            d_object_cls_loss_real = F.cross_entropy(out_logits_cls, objs)
    
                # Backward and optimizloe.
            d_loss = 0
            d_loss += config.lambda_img_adv * (d_image_adv_loss_fake + d_image_adv_loss_real)
            d_loss += config.lambda_obj_adv * (d_object_adv_loss_fake + d_object_adv_loss_real)
            d_loss += config.lambda_obj_cls * d_object_cls_loss_real
    
            netD_image.zero_grad()
            netD_object.zero_grad()
    
            d_loss.backward()
    
            netD_image_optimizer.step()
            netD_object_optimizer.step()
    
                # Logging.
            loss = {}
            loss['D/loss'] = d_loss.item()
            loss['D/image_adv_loss_real'] = d_image_adv_loss_real.item()
            loss['D/image_adv_loss_fake'] = d_image_adv_loss_fake.item()
            loss['D/object_adv_loss_real'] = d_object_adv_loss_real.item()
            loss['D/object_adv_loss_fake'] = d_object_adv_loss_fake.item()
            loss['D/object_cls_loss_real'] = d_object_cls_loss_real.item()
    
                # =================================================================================== #
                #                               3. Train the generator                                #
                # =================================================================================== #
                # Generate fake image
            output = netG(imgs, objs, boxes, masks, obj_to_img, z)
            crops_input, crops_input_rec, crops_rand, img_rec, img_rand, mu, logvar, z_rand_rec = output
    
                # reconstruction loss of ae and img
                # g_img_rec_loss = torch.abs(img_rec - imgs).view(imgs.shape[0], -1).mean(1)
            g_img_rec_loss = torch.abs(img_rec - imgs).mean()
            g_z_rec_loss = torch.abs(z_rand_rec - z).mean()
    
                # kl loss
            kl_element = mu.pow(2).add_(logvar.exp()).mul_(-1).add_(1).add_(logvar)
            g_kl_loss = torch.sum(kl_element).mul_(-0.5)
    
                # Compute image adv loss with fake images.
            out_logits = netD_image(img_rec)
            g_image_adv_loss_fake_rec = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 1))
    
            out_logits = netD_image(img_rand)
            g_image_adv_loss_fake_rand = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits, torch.full_like(out_logits, 1))
    
            g_image_adv_loss_fake = 0.5 * g_image_adv_loss_fake_rec + 0.5 * g_image_adv_loss_fake_rand
    
                # Compute object adv loss with fake images.
            out_logits_src, out_logits_cls = netD_object(crops_input_rec, objs)
            g_object_adv_loss_rec = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits_src,
                                                                           torch.full_like(out_logits_src, 1))
            g_object_cls_loss_rec = F.cross_entropy(out_logits_cls, objs)
    
            out_logits_src, out_logits_cls = netD_object(crops_rand, objs)
            g_object_adv_loss_rand = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(out_logits_src,
                                                                            torch.full_like(out_logits_src, 1))
            g_object_cls_loss_rand = F.cross_entropy(out_logits_cls, objs)
    
            g_object_adv_loss = 0.5 * g_object_adv_loss_rec + 0.5 * g_object_adv_loss_rand
            g_object_cls_loss = 0.5 * g_object_cls_loss_rec + 0.5 * g_object_cls_loss_rand
    
                # Backward and optimize.
            g_loss = 0
            g_loss += config.lambda_img_rec * g_img_rec_loss
            g_loss += config.lambda_z_rec * g_z_rec_loss
            g_loss += config.lambda_img_adv * g_image_adv_loss_fake
            g_loss += config.lambda_obj_adv * g_object_adv_loss
            g_loss += config.lambda_obj_cls * g_object_cls_loss
            g_loss += config.lambda_kl * g_kl_loss
    
            netG.zero_grad()
            g_loss.backward()
            netG_optimizer.step()
    
            loss['G/loss'] = g_loss.item()
            loss['G/image_adv_loss'] = g_image_adv_loss_fake.item()
            loss['G/object_adv_loss'] = g_object_adv_loss.item()
            loss['G/object_cls_loss'] = g_object_cls_loss.item()
            loss['G/rec_img'] = g_img_rec_loss.item()
            loss['G/rec_z'] = g_z_rec_loss.item()
            loss['G/kl'] = g_kl_loss.item()
    
                # =================================================================================== #
                #                               4. Log                                                #
                # =================================================================================== #
            if (i + 1) % config.log_step == 0:
                log = 'iter [{:06d}/{:06d}]'.format(i + 1, config.niter)
                for tag, roi_value in loss.items():
                    log += ", {}: {:.4f}".format(tag, roi_value)
                print(log)
    
            if (i + 1) % config.tensorboard_step == 0 and config.use_tensorboard:
                for tag, roi_value in loss.items():
                    writer.add_scalar(tag, roi_value, i + 1)
                writer.add_image('Result/crop_real', imagenet_deprocess_batch(crops_input).float() / 255, i + 1)
                writer.add_image('Result/crop_real_rec', imagenet_deprocess_batch(crops_input_rec).float() / 255, i + 1)
                writer.add_image('Result/crop_rand', imagenet_deprocess_batch(crops_rand).float() / 255, i + 1)
                writer.add_image('Result/img_real', imagenet_deprocess_batch(imgs).float() / 255, i + 1)
                writer.add_image('Result/img_real_rec', imagenet_deprocess_batch(img_rec).float() / 255, i + 1)
                writer.add_image('Result/img_fake_rand', imagenet_deprocess_batch(img_rand).float() / 255, i + 1)
    
            if (i + 1) % config.save_step == 0:
                save_model(netG, model_dir=model_save_dir, appendix='netG', iter=i + 1, save_num=5,
                            save_step=config.save_step)
                save_model(netD_image, model_dir=model_save_dir, appendix='netD_image', iter=i + 1, save_num=5,
                            save_step=config.save_step)
                save_model(netD_object, model_dir=model_save_dir, appendix='netD_object', iter=i + 1, save_num=5,
                            save_step=config.save_step)
    
        if config.use_tensorboard: writer.close()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    
        # Training configuration
        parser.add_argument('--dataset', type=str, default='publaynet')
        #parser.add_argument('--vg_dir', type=str, default='datasets/vg')
        parser.add_argument('--coco_dir', type=str, default='/home/user/PycharmProjects/synth_doc_layout/layout2im/datasets/annotations/')
        parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=8)
        parser.add_argument('--niter', type=int, default=300000, help='number of training iteration')
        parser.add_argument('--image_size', type=int, default=128, help='image size')
        parser.add_argument('--object_size', type=int, default=64, help='object size')
        parser.add_argument('--embedding_dim', type=int, default=64)
        parser.add_argument('--z_dim', type=int, default=64)
        parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=1e-4)
        parser.add_argument('--resi_num', type=int, default=6)
        parser.add_argument('--clstm_layers', type=int, default=3)
    
        # Loss weight
        parser.add_argument('--lambda_img_adv', type=float, default=1.0, help='weight of adv img')
        parser.add_argument('--lambda_obj_adv', type=float, default=1.0, help='weight of adv obj')
        parser.add_argument('--lambda_obj_cls', type=float, default=1.0, help='weight of aux obj')
        parser.add_argument('--lambda_z_rec', type=float, default=10.0, help='weight of z rec')
        parser.add_argument('--lambda_img_rec', type=float, default=1.0, help='weight of image rec')
        parser.add_argument('--lambda_kl', type=float, default=0.01, help='weight of kl')
    
        # Log setting
        parser.add_argument('--resume_iter', type=str, default='l',
                            help='l: from latest; s: from scratch; xxx: from iteration xxx')
        parser.add_argument('--log_step', type=int, default=10)
        parser.add_argument('--tensorboard_step', type=int, default=100)
        parser.add_argument('--save_step', type=int, default=1000)
        parser.add_argument('--use_tensorboard', type=str2bool, default='true')
    
        config = parser.parse_args()
        config.exp_name = 'layout2im_{}'.format(config.dataset)
        print(config)
        main(config)
```

Please How I can solve this issue?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It bases on your Pytorch model structure. But the key of freezing layer in Pytorch is

```py
param.requires_grad = False
```

If you want to freeze only some first layers, use counter and set `requires_grad = False` to that layer

Or you can explicitly do like this

```py
net.fc.weight.requres_grad = False
```

to freeze `fully connected` layer of model named `net`

Comment: ` start_iter = load_model(netG, model_dir=model_save_dir, appendix='netG', iter=config.resume_iter)
    _ = load_model(netD_image, model_dir=model_save_dir, appendix='netD_image', iter=config.resume_iter)
    _ = load_model(netD_object, model_dir=model_save_dir, appendix='netD_object', iter=config.resume_iter)
    for param in start_iter.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False`

Comment: is it ocrrect like this ? how I loaded and fine tuned the models? thanks

Comment: @sarahx No, is must be `for param in net.parameters()` with `net` is  model likes `netD_image`, `netD_object`, `netD`, not an integer likes `start_iter`

Comment: thank you very much, actually I trained my model on huge data publaynet and then I want to fine tune the models to run it again with another small data. Is there anything else I need to adapt for the code to accomplish this? thanks

Comment: In case you use different datasets to train same model, my advice is no need to freeze your network. When you want to transfer knowledge from model trained on publaynet dataset, you just do this `model.load_state_dict(torch.load(load_model))` with `load_model` is path to 
 your trained weight on publaynet dataset. Then use `model` as normally

Comment: my data is small it contain 1000 image, so it will not be a problem?

Comment: actually I got an error of size mismatch when I load my models how I can solve it ?

Comment: I uodated the code please check it and help me out

Comment: What is your `config.embedding_dim` and `vocab_num`?

Comment: config.embedding_dim = 64 and vocab_num = 10